# Paramiko executable: not found on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, paramiko

I used Paramiko 1.7.7.1 to send remote command to Windows XP.

I tried to send a simple command e.g ipconfig and grabs the stderr by using the recv exit status. It returns the ip address on my client machine. However, when I try to issue a call of an executable installed on the Windows XP, it says:-

myapp.exe : not found

The weird thing is on my server side, I could issue myapp.exe and the executable could be invoked without any problem. By the way, I have set the environment variable for the myapp.exe on Windows XP properly.

Could anyone provide me some help to solve this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To call an executable under Windows using Paramiko, try :

```
cmd /c executable
```